# How to acces a view from tableViewCell to TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and `UITableViewCell`. Now I am try to access a view from a `UITableViewCell` to `UITableViewController` by `didSelectRowAt` function. But I could not do it.

**TableViewController**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FlipViewCon: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    let flipCellId = "flipCellid"

    let flipTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .green

        return tableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray

        flipTableView.delegate = self
        flipTableView.dataSource = self

        flipTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

        self.view.addSubview(flipTableView)

        flipTableView.register(FlipTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: flipCellId)
    }

    let countryArray = ["bangladesh", "nepal", "china", "malaysia", "thai land", "japan", "England", "canada"]
    let cityArray = ["Dhake","Kathmandu",  "Beijing", "Kuala Lumpur", "Bangkok", "tokeyo", "London", "Torento"]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countryArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: flipCellId, for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCell

        //cell.textLabel?.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.zeroLabel.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.oneLabel.text = cityArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.transition(with: FlipTableViewCell.zeroView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)

        FlipTableViewCell.zeroView.isHidden = true
        FlipTableViewCell.oneView.isHidden = false
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.transition(with: FlipTableViewCell.oneView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)

        FlipTableViewCell.zeroView.isHidden = false
        FlipTableViewCell.oneView.isHidden = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.flipTableView.frame.width / 4
    }
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class FlipTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    static let zeroView = flipView(myColor: .yellow)
    static let oneView = flipView(myColor: .green)

    static func flipView(myColor: UIColor) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = myColor

        return view
    }

    let zeroLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "Zero 0"
        return lb
    }()

    let oneLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "one 1"
        return lb
    }()

    func setupView(){
        FlipTableViewCell.zeroView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height:frame.height)
        FlipTableViewCell.oneView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

        self.addSubview(FlipTableViewCell.zeroView)
        self.addSubview(FlipTableViewCell.oneView)

        zeroLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 50)
        oneLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y:0, width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 50)

        addSubview(zeroLabel)
        addSubview(oneLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath)` method, inside `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: @Sam please come to more details friend!

Comment: As a side note, I don't see how you're going to be successful with using those static zeroView and oneView.  You're only going to have one of each for your entire app, yet you are trying to stick them into each UITableViewCell as a subview.  All you'll really be doing is moving them from one cell to another as you'll be re-parenting them.

Comment: @Emma Ani  checkout my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell {
        UIView.transition(with: cell.zeroView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)

        cell.zeroView.isHidden = true
        cell.oneView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I have update your `FlipTableViewCell`

it looks like this

```
class FlipTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var zeroView : UIView!
    var oneView : UIView!

    func flipView(myColor: UIColor) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = myColor

        return view
    }

    let zeroLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "Zero 0"
        return lb
    }()

    let oneLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "one 1"
        return lb
    }()

    func setupView(){
        zeroView = flipView(myColor: .yellow)
        oneView  = flipView(myColor: .green)

        zeroView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height:frame.height)
        oneView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

        self.addSubview(zeroView)
        self.addSubview(oneView)

        zeroLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 50)
        oneLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y:0, width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 50)

        addSubview(zeroLabel)
        addSubview(oneLabel)
    }
}
```

And Change some code in `FlipViewCon`

```
class FlipViewCon: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    let flipCellId = "flipCellid"

    let flipTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .green

        return tableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray

        flipTableView.delegate = self
        flipTableView.dataSource = self

        flipTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

        self.view.addSubview(flipTableView)

        flipTableView.register(FlipTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: flipCellId)
    }

    let countryArray = ["bangladesh", "nepal", "china", "malaysia", "thai land", "japan", "England", "canada"]
    let cityArray = ["Dhake","Kathmandu",  "Beijing", "Kuala Lumpur", "Bangkok", "tokeyo", "London", "Torento"]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countryArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: flipCellId, for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCell

        //cell.textLabel?.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.zeroLabel.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.oneLabel.text = cityArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell {
            UIView.transition(with: cell.zeroView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)

            cell.zeroView.isHidden = true
            cell.oneView.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell {
            UIView.transition(with: cell.zeroView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)

            cell.zeroView.isHidden = false
            cell.oneView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.flipTableView.frame.width / 4
    }
}
```

**Edit2**
Replace this method in above solution

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell {
            UIView.transition(with: cell.oneView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)

            cell.zeroView.isHidden = false
            cell.oneView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: This will fail as the user scrolls.

Comment: @rmaddy can you help me please! i sure that you know how to solve my problem

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya it is just flips `yellowView` without textLabel, next greenView never flip at all. Friend please try to correct, i hope you can to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCell
    // TODO:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like all the other answers on this post, use the `cellForRow(at: IndexPath)` method on `UITableView`, to get a reference to the cells in the table view.

This method returns a `UITableViewCell`, if the cell is loaded (visible) and `nil` if the indexPath is not correct or the cell is not loaded.

The code should look like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    // Do something with cell.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TableViewController**

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit

class FlipViewCon: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    let flipCellId = "flipCellid"

    let flipTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .green
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        return tableView
    }()


    let countryArray = ["India","bangladesh", "nepal", "china", "malaysia", "thai land", "japan", "England", "canada"]
    let cityArray = ["Delhi","Dhake","Kathmandu",  "Beijing", "Kuala Lumpur", "Bangkok", "tokeyo", "London", "Torento"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray

        flipTableView.delegate = self
        flipTableView.dataSource = self

        flipTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

        self.view.addSubview(flipTableView)

        self.resetFlag()

        flipTableView.register(FlipTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: flipCellId)


    }
    var flagArray : [String] = []

    func resetFlag() {

        flagArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        for _ in 0 ..< self.countryArray.count {
            self.flagArray.append("0")
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countryArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: flipCellId, for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCell

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        if flagArray[indexPath.row] == "0" {
            cell.zeroView.isHidden = false
            cell.oneView.isHidden = true
        }else{
            cell.zeroView.isHidden = true
            cell.oneView.isHidden = false
        }

        cell.zeroLabel.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.oneLabel.text = cityArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell {

            self.flagArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.flagArray.insert("1", at: indexPath.row)

            UIView.transition(with: cell.zeroView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: { (complete) in
                cell.zeroView.isHidden = true
                cell.oneView.isHidden = false
            })

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell {

            self.flagArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.flagArray.insert("0", at: indexPath.row)

            UIView.transition(with: cell.oneView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: { (complete) in
                cell.zeroView.isHidden = false
                cell.oneView.isHidden = true
            })

        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.flipTableView.frame.width / 4
    }
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
    import UIKit

class FlipTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

     let zeroView = flipView(myColor: .yellow)
     let oneView = flipView(myColor: .green)

    static func flipView(myColor: UIColor) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = myColor

        return view
    }

    let zeroLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "Zero 0"
        return lb
    }()

    let oneLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "one 1"
        return lb
    }()

    func setupView(){
        zeroView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height:frame.width/4)
        oneView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.width/4)

        self.addSubview(oneView)
        self.addSubview(zeroView)


        zeroLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: (frame.width/4)/2 - 25, width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 50)
        oneLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y:(frame.width/4)/2 - 25, width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 50)

        zeroView.addSubview(zeroLabel)
        oneView.addSubview(oneLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail as the user scrolls the table view and the cells get reused.

Comment: To solve this problem we have to maintain array list with flag for ex. ON/OFF

Comment: i am agree with rmaddy. but now i need help

Comment: wait @EmmaAni I will send you solved example. Can you please share UI screenshot for cell

Comment: @SomParkash i am waiting for you with eagerness

Comment: Hey @EmmaAni I edited the answer. Please try this and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: @SomParkash `didSelectRowAt` flips  without textLabel, and `didDeselectRowAt` does nothing.  i have two array one is countryArray and cityArray. countryArray show default and cityArray show by flip when i will click  on `didDeselectRowAt`